# Given N coins, each coin can be used at most T times. Is it possible to make value W using minimum N coins?

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming, coin-change

**Input Format:**

N T (N = number of coins, T = number of times) 
C1, C2 .... CN 
W

From my solution, I am getting this...

**Input:**
2 4
5 8
37

**Output:**
5 (Which is valid, because 37 = (8*4)+(5*1))

**Input:**
2 2 
5 10 
30

**Output:**
3 (Here the output should be **4**, because I can't use coins more than 2 times).

**Where is the error in my solution?**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int coins[100], N, T, mem[100][100];
int solve(int p, int w, int us[])
{
    if(p==N || w<=0){
        if(w==0) return 0;
        return 1e5;
    }
    if(mem[w][p]!=-1) return mem[w][p];
    int ans=1e5;

    if(us[p]<T){
        us[p]++;
        ans=min(1+solve(p, w-coins[p], us), ans);
        us[p]--;
    }
    ans=min(ans, solve(p+1, w, us));
    return mem[w][p]=ans;
}
int main()
{
    cin>>N>>T;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        cin>>coins[i];
    }
    int w, us[100];
    cin>>w;
    memset(mem, -1, sizeof (mem));
    memset(us, 0, sizeof (us));
    cout<<solve(0, w, us)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is max of value of w 100?

Comment: Yes, I am just using 100 table size for testing purpose, It will be okay if my second input shows the correct result. Thank you @GolamMazidSajib

Comment: max value of T?

Comment: max value of T = 50

Comment: What is the definition of output? Like the question seems to be yes/no, yet the answer is 3/5 what are these numbers?

Comment: output is minimum number of coins used to make value W. Output 5 means..coin 8 used 4 times and coin 5 used 1 times. (4+1)=5 coin is used which is minimum number. 3 is actually wrong answer. It should be 4, but showing 3, because I can't use any coins more than T times. Thank you @GrzegorzSkibinski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Code Problem:

you check `if(us[p]<T)` but when call function u subtract `w-coins[p]`...

According to your logic this block:

```
if(us[p]<T){
        us[p]++;
        ans=min(1+solve(p, w-coins[p], us), ans);
        us[p]--;
    }
```

would be:

```
if(us[coins[p]]<T){
        us[coins[p]]++;
        ans=min(1+solve(p, w-coins[p], us), ans);
        us[coins[p]]--;
    }
```

#### Your Solution problem:

Your memorization will not work cause u pass `p,w and us[]` in function but you memorize only `p and w`.. As you memorize all state of same value `p and w` and different value of `us[]`.. your solution will not works..

#### Solution:

You need to take new array with coin array T times...

Lets coin : `5, 10`.. and `t = 2`

Then new array coin array will be: `5 5 10 10`

Now if you want to make `30` then try to make `30` using new array:

Try with this code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
int coins[5005], N, M, T, mem[105][5005];
int solve(int p, int w)
{
    if(p==N || w<=0){
        if(w==0) return 0;
        return 1e5;
    }
    if(mem[w][p]!=-1)
        return mem[w][p];
    return mem[w][p] = min(solve(p+1,w), 1 + solve(p+1, w-coins[p]));
}
int main()
{
    cin>>N>>T;
    M = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        int a;
        cin>>a;
        for (int j = 0; j < T; j++) {
            coins[M++] = a;
        }
    }
    N = M;
    int w, us[100];
    cin>>w;
    memset(mem, -1, sizeof (mem));
    cout<<solve(0, w)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After trying your solution, output is still 3 for the second testcase! I need a solution. You can modify my code for the right verdict. Thanks

Comment: @MinhajulIslam i did not give solution ... detect error in your code als give error of your logic... i can give hint only in answer. u need to try

Comment: Got it! You just implement min number of coins to make value W where, coins can be used at most once. The coin array has all coins at most T times. Nice.... Btw, I also solved it using a loop in the recursive function. Thank you bhai @GolamMazidSajib